# How to calculate output from predictive model equation that is stored in database format using SAS or SQL

Tags: sql, model, sas

For this example, i do not mind if it's solved using SAS, or any SQL language

What I want to do, is productionise model equations so that I can calculate a prediction on the fly

I have a lookup, that stores all model equations

For this example we can assume the formula is always intercept + coef1*var1 + coef2*var2 etc

```
model   coef    variable
churn   0.8 intercept
churn   0.5 var1
churn   -0.2    var2
churn   0.2 var3
```

I then have a denormalised table of variables for each customer i.e.

```
customer_id var1    var2    var3
a   3   2   4
b   5   1   2
c   2   4   5
```

The output I want is the prediction from the formula for each customer
I.e. for customer a:

```
The output would be the result of 0.8 + 0.5*3 + -0.2*2 + 0.2*4
```

What is the best way to have this model information stored in a database, and for me to calculations on the fly, Do I need to normalise the customer table so that I can directly join on each variable?

Comment: Depends on how you want to use them.  What does "on the fly" mean?  Certainly normalizing the customer table is a good choice, but you can also work with the data the way you have it; but it depends on how you are using the data.

Answer (score 1):

Normalizing the customer data is certainly going to be the easier way if you're doing this in SQL within SAS.  If you're doing it in SQL Server, you could probably use `pivot` to get things in the same direction.

In base SAS, I would do the opposite.  Two options: `PROC SCORE` or a simple data step.

`PROC SCORE` is really intended for this purpose.  Either way you need to `PROC TRANSPOSE` the normalized model data into one row, if you're doing the data step version make sure to add a prefix using the `prefix` option (say `model_var1` etc.), then do one of the following:

```
data model;
  input model $ coef variable :$10.;
  datalines;
churn   0.8 intercept
churn   0.5 var1
churn   -0.2    var2
churn   0.2 var3
;;;;
run;

data have;
input customer_id $ var1    var2    var3;
datalines;
a   3   2   4
b   5   1   2
c   2   4   5
;;;;
run;

proc transpose data=model out=model_score;
  id variable;
  by model;
run;


data model_score_fin;
  set model_score;
  drop _name_;
  rename
    model = _model_;
  _type_ = 'PARMS';
run;


proc score data=have out=want_score score=model_score_fin type=parms predict  nostd;
  var var1 var2 var3;
run;
```

or

```
proc transpose data=model out=model_t prefix=model_;
id variable;
where model="churn";
run;

data want;
  if _n_=1 then set model_t;
  set have;
  array models model_var:;
  array vars var:;
  result = model_intercept;
  do _i = 1 to dim(vars);
    result = sum(result,models[_i]*vars[_i]);
  end;
run;
```

Finally, if you have `SAS IML`, you can easily do this by transposing (like above or with `IML` transpose operator) and then use matrix multiplication.